# How to send html email?

Tags: php, pear

I need to send html email. So I am using [PEAR library](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/about.pear.php) with [Mail extension](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.mail.mail-mime.example.php)

So I have written this code:

```
include('Mail.php');
include('Mail/mime.php');

$email = "xxx@gmail.com";
$from_addr = "example <yyy@gmail.com>";
$message_subject ="Test";    
$text =  "
Hello.
This is a link:

http//:www.hardevent.net/index.php

byebye
";

$html = "<html>
<body>
<p>
Hellooooo, this is a link:
</p>
<a href=\"http://www.google.com\"/>Gooooo</a>
</body>
</html>";

                     $headers = array ("From" => $from_addr,
                                       "To" => $email,
                                       "Subject" => $message_subject);


                     $crlf = "\n";
                     $mime = new Mail_mime($crlf);
                     $mime->setTXTBody($text);
                     $mime->setHTMLBody($html);
                     $body = $mime->get();
                     $hdrs = $mime->headers($headers);
                     $smtp = Mail::factory("smtp", array ('host' => "smtp.xxx.com",
                                                          'auth' => true,
                                                          'username' => "xxx",
                                                          'password' => "xxx"));
                     $mail = $smtp->send($email, $hdrs, $body);
```

But this is the email that I see ( only text without link ):

```
Object: Test
Hellooooo, this is a link:

Gooooo
```

why ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typo?

```
<a href=\"http://www.google.com\">Gooooo</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

You are closing the link:

```
<a href=\"http://www.google.com\"/>
```

The trailing `/` needs to be removed.

Answer (score 1):

Try single quoting the link `<a href='http://www.google.com'>Gooooo</a>`